# Slow data processing mulesoft Batch Processing

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft

I am using Batch Processing in Mulesoft but the issue is like the data load is very slow. Tried removing the entries in ObjectStore but no luck.

Is the population of ObjsectStore slowing down the data load? Or what can be the root cause?

I tried clearing ObjectStore with Clear Application Data tab as Always but it works only on local and that too for only small load of data

Clicked the Clear Application Data as Always in Configuration

ObjectStore Entries not getting deleted as expected

Comment: And the usual welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Comment: Any help on the issue please? thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Experts, Really appreciate any help

Comment: I am under tight deadline by tomorrow,really appreciate your help

Comment: It is not possible to answer the question as it is. It is too wide and too little information provided. It is like asking my for loop in Java is slow, provide a fix. You need to ask a more specific question here. That might need some debugging on your part to identify what part is slow, or if the problem is too complex divide it into smaller problems.

Comment: As mentioned above, its hard to to say without actually seeing the code whats slowing down, it could be bottlenecks anywhere.It could even be memory issues in the server or do u have any domain projects. Please give us much detailed information to get prompt responses.